# What information do IOTA nodes store?

Tags: light-node, scalability

I considering IOTA for some nodes with very limited resources. In terms of storage and connection to the internet, what is the minimum necessary to have IOTA working in these nodes?

Comment: Are you talking about full nodes (store Tangle) or light nodes (ask full nodes to give them infos about the Tangle)?

Comment: I am asking about both types, in order to be able to discern when it is worth it to use one and when the other when resources are limited and unreliable.

Answer (score 1):

The way I understand it, full nodes store every transaction that they and their neighbors are aware of. From, to, amount, message, tag, trunk/branch transactions, etc. They also store information about wallet addresses, such as balances.

Light nodes don't store much at all. Instead, they use API calls to the full node they are connected to, to get the information you requested. Things like balance, history, addresses.

Comment: Can you add any references that back up your information?